# log4jでRuntimeExceptionのStacktraceを出力したいです。

Tags: java

こんにちは。

現在、java（tomcatのアプリケーション）で作ったシステムがすでに本番稼動中なのですが、つい先日、想定外のエラーが発生しました。（java.sql.SQLExceptionでした。）

エラーの原因自体はわかったのですが、ログがlog4jのログファイルではなく、
tomcatのログファイル（localhost.yyyy-mm-dd.log）に出力されたことが問題となり、
ログの集約を求められました。

もちろん、exceptionが発生しそうな場所に
logger.error・・
をしかけておけばよいのですが、そもそも今の作りとして、ほとんどlogger.errorを
しかけていないので、エラーログを出力するためにアプリケーションを直さなくてはならない、
というのがあまりいい策でないと思っています。

log4jの設定ファイル変更で対応できないかと思っているのですが、可能でしょうか・・。

ご存じの方いらっしゃれば、コメントをお願いします！

Comment: ありがとうございました。
教えていただいたサイトを参考に解決しました。

サイトのjarファイルがリンク切れとなっていたので、自分でソースからビルドしなおししたり、バージョンの差なのか、起動スクリプト（catalina.sh）の変更点が「JAVA_OPT」の追加でなく、「LOGGING_CONFIG」へのlog4j.propertisの追加だった点が多少苦労しましたが、なんとか目的達成です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こちらが参考になるでしょうか。

tomcat6 のログ出力を Log4j で行う方法：
http://www.deftrash.com/blog/archives/2008/06/tomcat6_log4j.html